# Add index firebase firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I already add an index on firebase firestore but when I call API, it's shows an error.

> FAILED_PRECONDITION: no matching index found.

Where am I wrong or what am I missing? If you know please tell me. Thank you very much. This is my code:

```
  firebaseGirls.orderBy("updatedAt", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .whereEqualTo("type", Constants.VIDEO)
            .limit(Constants.LIMIT_DEFAULT)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                if (!result.isEmpty) {
                    val data = result.toObjects(Video::class.java)
                    lastVisible = result.documents[result.size() - 1]
                    binding.viewPagerVideos.adapter = VideosAdapter(data as ArrayList<Video>)
                } else {
                    toastLong("No Data")
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.wtf("loadImagesFromFirebase: ", "error: ${exception.message}")
                toastLong("${exception.message}")
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried this index: `type Ascending, updatedAt Descending` ?

Comment: Yep, you can see in image, i try every way but it's still not work

Comment: I can't see any index having `type Ascending` in the screenshot.

Comment: How is  `firebaseGirls` defined? Besides that, have you tried @Dharmaraj solution `type Ascending, updatedAt Descending`?

Comment: I know why it's not working, we need to create an index here: https://console.cloud.google.com/firestore/indexes/composite?create_composite=ClJwcm9qZWN0cy90dWRpZW5kYW5obmdvbi1iYTZiYy9kYXRhYmFzZXMvKGRlZmF1bHQpL2NvbGxlY3Rpb25Hcm91cHMvZ2lybHMvaW5kZXhlcy9fEAEaCAoEdHlwZRABGg0KCXVwZGF0ZWRBdBACGgwKCF9fbmFtZV9fEAI&pli=1&authuser=4&project=tudiendanhngon-ba6bc&folder=&organizationId=